# Overloading operator+ and Segmentation fault C++

Tags: c++

so im designing a program that creates a matrix using vector of vectors of int and im trying to overload the + so that i can add two matrices together. This is my 1st time overloading an operator and im having a bit of trouble. I implemented the operator+ and when i run it using a tester class, i get a Segmentation fault and it doesnt tell me where. So i added cout to see where it went wrong; it happens when i call matrix2 = matrix1 +matrix2. Im dont know what there error means or what i did wrong.

Matrix.cpp (where the overload member function is):

```
Matrix Matrix::operator+(Matrix m){
    vector<int> mRow;
    vector<int> newRow;
    Matrix newM(row, column);
    for(int i =0; i<row; i++){
        mRow = m.getRow(i);
        for (int j=column; j<0; j--){
            newRow.push_back(matrix[i][j]+mRow[j]);
        }
        newM.setRow(newRow,i);  
    }
    return newM;
}
```

TesterClass.cpp:

```
Matrix m2(rowVec.size(), colVec.size());
    rowVec = matrix.getRow(1);
    cout <<"Made new matrix" <<endl;
    for (int i=0; i <= row-1; i++){
        cout <<"for l" <<endl;
        m2.setRow(rowVec,i);
    }

    cout <<"for done" <<endl;
    Matrix add(row,column); 
    add = matrix + m2; #Program stops here
    cout <<"added" <<endl;
    add.output();
```

Comment: `for (int j=column; j<0; j--)` ???  Are you sure that `j<0` ?? Shouldn't you start at `j=column-1` ?

Comment: Also, newRow seems to be just appended to for each row. So each row, if they were set, would get bigger and bigger. (Also, you almost certainly want to use const references and not copy the argument to +). Or exploit the fact that the argument to operator + will be a copy, and just return it after adding to it. `for() for() m[i][j]+=this[i][j];`

Comment: And you're sure in the tester class that add, matrix and m2 have the same number of rows and columns ?  And you're sure that you have correctly defined operator=() ?

Comment: @perh i forgot to reset newRow when its added to the metrix

Comment: @Christophe ya im sure its the same size as i hardcode the size and what not for the purpose of debugging the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spot an off-by-one error in the inner loop of the addition. The for loop initializes `j` to `column` but should start at `j=column-1`. That would cause a segfault when accessing `mRow[j]`. Also the condition should changed, be `for (j = column - 1; j > -1; --j)`

Comment: However, that will not cause a crash since the inner loop will always be skipped entirely (i=positive; i<0; i--)